# DataTrigger binding to buttons in UserControl not working in MainWindow

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 6 same elements including text box, image and two buttons. For images i have DataTrigger which acts when i press one of two buttons and rotates image by 90 deg. DataTrigger has Binding to btnLeft, and its working when this two buttons are in Main Window and have names btnLeft and btnRight. But there is 6 of it, i cant name 6 same Left and Right buttons by different names! I moved this buttons to local class (USerControl) and then used they in MainWindow. But Data Trigger not working with it. What should i do?
This is style for images with DataTrigger:

```
<Window.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="rotateImg">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnLeft, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" By="90" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is one of 6 same elements:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource stack0}" Background="White">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=img1, Path=Source}"/>
        <Image x:Name="img1" Style="{StaticResource rotateImg}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" >
               <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
         </Image>
         <local:Imgs/>
</StackPanel>
```

^ There is line local:Imgs/ which directs to class Imgs with buttons. Here is it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Lab1.Imgs"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lab1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="130">
        <Button Width="30" Height="30" Margin="0 10 30 0" x:Name="btnLeft">
            <Image Source="imgs\Left.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Width="30" Height="30" Margin="30 10 0 0" x:Name="btnRight">
            <Image Source="imgs\Right.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Its working only when i define the buttons in MainWindow instead of line local:Imgs/. But how i said before, in that case i have to name 6 same buttons by different names

Comment: Why don't you create a UserControl that contains the TextBox, Image and two Buttons? The UserControl could expose a property for the Image's Source.

Comment: @Clemens because images in this elements are different. That would be great if i could change Image's Source for each 6 elements, but i dont think i can

Comment: Sure, that is why the control would expose a property. And is the Text in the TextBox really editable? Otherwise use a TextBlock.

Comment: well, that makes sense, ill try it

Comment: A Binding in the control's XAML to the control's own property would use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`. The property should be declared as dependency property to support data binding, styles etc.